# How to fit ASP.NET page in any screen size?

Tags: asp.net, web

I have my ASP.NET
[page with 100% zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLYu0.jpg)

And it should look like this
[page with 85% zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A6yM.jpg)

Any idea?

*Dots inserted because stackoverflow requires more description*
.............................................................................................................................................
MasterPage Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logoMAGA.png" />
    <!-- Required meta tags -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="/css/style-navbar2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CHOSEN -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" />

    <!-- JQuery MODAL DINAMICO-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-show-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Jquery DATA TABLE -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Jquery DATA TABLE CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- ICONOS FONT AWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.telefono').keyup(function () {
                this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            });

            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
            })

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark titulo" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <img class="logo horizontal-logo" height="60px" width="40px" src="/img/logoMAGA.png" alt="forecastr logo">
                    &nbsp
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-5 hola">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Productos</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Productos/ProductosMain.aspx">Catálogo</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Inventario
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Inventario/Inventario.aspx">Inventario</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Inventario/Entrada_Maestra.aspx"">Entrada Maestra</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Inventario/MovimientosInventarioMain.aspx">Movimientos de inventario</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clasificación
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Clasificacion/ClasificacionMain.aspx">Clasificaciones</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clientes
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Clientes/ClientesMain.aspx">Catálogo</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ventas
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Ventas/Registro_Ventas.aspx">Registrar ventas</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Ventas/Historial_Ventas.aspx">Historial ventas</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Ventas/Registro_Ventas.aspx">Registrar Factura de ventas</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Ventas/Ver_Facturas_Ventas.aspx">Historial-Factura de ventas</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Compras
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Compras/Ordenes_Compra.aspx">Registro de compras</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Compras/Historial_Compras.aspx">Historial Ordenes de compra</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Compras/Registro_Factura_Compra.aspx">Registro de facturas</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Compras/Historial_Facturas_Compras.aspx">Historial Facturas de compra</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pedidos
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Pedidos/Estatus_Pedido.aspx">Estatus de pedidos</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Proveedores
                        </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Proveedores/ProveedoresMain.aspx">Principal</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Proveedores/Cotizaciones_Proveedores.aspx">Cotización de proveedores</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Proveedores/Precios_Proveedores.aspx">Actualizar precios de proveedores</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Proveedores/Comparacion_Proveedores.aspx">Comparar precios</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="fa fa-cog"></span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Configuraciones/Proveedores_Productos.aspx">Asignación Proveedores-Producto</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Configuraciones/UnidadMain.aspx">Unidades de medida</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Configuraciones/SucursalesMain.aspx">Sucursales</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Posicion/PosicionesMain.aspx">Posiciones</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Personal/PersonalMain.aspx">Personal</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Configuraciones/Mi_Cuenta.aspx">Mi cuenta</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown" onclick="ExecCerrarSesion();">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCerrarSesion" runat="server" CssClass="nav-link" OnClick="lnkCerrarSesion_Click">
                                        <span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <br />
        <br />
        <footer class="bg-dark">
            <br />
            <div class="text-center text-white">
                HAZ EL BIEN, HAZLO BIEN
            </div>
            <br />
        </footer>
    </form>
</body>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->


<script>
    const $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
    const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle");
    const $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
    const showClass = "show";

    $(window).on("load resize", function () {
        if (this.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
            $dropdown.hover(
                function () {
                    const $this = $(this);
                    $this.addClass(showClass);
                    $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
                    $this.find($dropdownMenu).addClass(showClass);
                },
                function () {
                    const $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass(showClass);
                    $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
                    $this.find($dropdownMenu).removeClass(showClass);
                }
            );
        } else {
            $dropdown.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
    });

    $(".chosen").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I've updated the post with my masterpage code

Comment: This is more a CSS / Layout issue. You can try less padding and/or margin between menu items, and lower font size.